# Race condition while using Atomic Integer

Tags: java, multithreading, atomic

I am learning about `java.util.concurrent.atomic` package and trying my hands on `Atomic Integer`. As per my understanding Atomic package helps to write lock-free code as opposed to using synchronized block. So to test my understanding I wrote the following code:

```
public class Test{

   private final AtomicInteger ai; 

   public void increment() {
        int oldVal = ai.get();

        while(!ai.compareAndSet(oldVal, oldVal+1)) {
            oldVal = ai.get();
        }
    }

    public int incrementModified() {
        return ai.incrementAndGet();
    }

    public int get() {
        return ai.get();
    }

public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test pc = new Test(5);

        Runnable r1 = () -> {
            pc.increment();
        };

        Runnable r2 = () -> {
            pc.increment();
        };

        Runnable r3 = () -> {
            pc.increment();
        };

        Thread t1 = new Thread(r1);

        Thread t2 = new Thread(r2);

        Thread t3 = new Thread(r3);

        t1.start();
        t2.start();
        t3.start();

        System.out.println(pc.get());

    }
```

When I execute the above code I expect the output to be **8** but I am getting output as **7/8**. Then I even used the inbuilt `incrementAndGet()` method and still got the same output after running the program a number of times.

As per my understanding since atomic can be used as an alternative to synchronized block and it makes the increment operations atomic by using CAS(compare and set instruction) I should always get the output as 8.

But since I am getting different outputs I assume there is a race existing and thus the o/p varies between 7/8.

Could someone point out the mistakes I am making in the above code or correct my understanding about atomic classes in Java?

**EDIT:**

As pointed out in the comments I didn't use `join()` and thus was getting incorrect result as main thread was requesting the value while some thread may still be in middle of the operation. I added it and after testing it a number of times I can see the expected result.

Comment: The line which prints the value executes concurrently to the other 3 threads. If you want to make sure it executes **after** the 3 threads have run, then you need to join() on those threads.

Comment: @JBNizet got it. Thanks a lot.

Comment: FYI, don't know how it is these days but in the past, OpenJDK's implementation of `getAndIncrement()` and `incrementAndGet()` used a CAS loop.

Comment: @Eric If I remember correctly what you said is true only if underlying hardware supports CAS which might not be the case. It may also make the use of spin-lock then.

Comment: @YugSingh, yep, of course. What I meant was that in older versions, `getAndIncrement()` was at best *lock-free* if the underlying hardware supported CAS, but it looks like newer versions of Java use Unsafe::getAndAddInt` which is annotated with `@HotspotIntrinsicCandidate`. A bit of digging shows that in the best case, `AtomicInteger::getAndIncrement` is *wait-free* if the hardware supports it.

Comment: You can use the same runnable in all 3 threads.  Also, you are missing the `Test` constructor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line which prints the value executes concurrently to the other 3 threads. If you want to make sure it executes after the 3 threads have run, then you need to join() on those threads.